# Get Notification when my android application crashes

Tags: android, error-handling, android-notifications

I would like to know if there is a mechanism or a tool that get the developer notified when its application crashes, once it is published in play store and being used by users.

Any idea or suggestion will be very appreciated !!!

Comment: You need some kind of a Crashlytic tool.

Comment: [Crashlytics](https://fabric.io/kits/android/crashlytics/install)

Comment: Use Crashlytics for getting report of crash after app uploaded to playstore

Comment: Ok, thanks, but there is nothing provided by Google ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Firebase it is free and google is supporting it. They are even including it in their play service lib.

https://firebase.google.com

Comment: ok, this will be perfect for me since i am using te firebase database and auth.

Comment: Great :) it is so easy to implement, you just need to include the lib dependency and the google-services.json for it to work

Answer (score 1):

**Crashlytics**

(Free, crashlytics.com)

The feature we like most about Crashlytics is how proactive it is. Unlike other tools, it takes into account how often a crash occurs and assigns it an “impact level." It will then alert you when a specific crash is more critical than another. As a particular crash is reported more and more, Crashlytics tracks that information and says "Hey, you haven’t resolved this issue yet and it’s starting to become something you need to focus on." It’s literally calling out the crashes that should be dealt with next

**Instabug**

($0-$129/month, instabug.com)

Most of our team agrees that Instabug provides the most useful information for troubleshooting a crash. That’s not to say that its crash logs are the best (see HockeyApp below). Instead, Instabug has more metadata that helps support debugging, including the specific steps users have taken in the app. Separately, by shaking the device, Instabug takes a screenshot that can be annotated by a user. That screenshot gets submitted along with other diagnostic information, all of which is automatically attached to the feedback

**HockeyApp**

($10-$500/month, hockeyapp.net)

HockeyApp is the winner when it comes to the depth and accuracy of crash logs. It does require more setup compared to other alternatives though. It also requires a manual process for uploading crash symbols. We agree overall with their assessment of the quality of their own and other crash logs

**Parse**

(Free with Core or Push package, parse.com)

Parse is a mid-level crash reporting tool. It doesn’t provide the most detailed console logs or the best alerts. The exciting thing about what we’ve seen with Parse though, is its newness and room for growth. Released in December 2014, we expect Parse to expand rapidly and add new features. It’s worth keeping an eye on, especially if they roll out crash reporting as a separate feature.

Answer (score 0):

1.[Crashlytics](https://get.fabric.io/?utm_campaign=crashlytics-marketing&utm_medium=natural) (Recommended)

You can see Real Time Crash Reports in Crashlytics.

2.[Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/)

Need 24 hour to get Crash Reports.

Support by Google.

Comment: No I am getting crash reports in like 10 min top with Firebase.